# Reset supervisor password on Lenovo Ideapad S10e

Tags: bios, passwords, phoenix, lenovo-laptop

I have an old Lenovo Ideapad S10e that a friend has given me. I need to be able to change settings such as the boot order in the BIOS setup, but I can not because there is a supervisor password. My friend does not remember the supervisor password. I can only access some BIOS settings with the user password. It has a Phoenix BIOS. No hard disk password or anything is set, only the supervisor password. I have done a lot of Googling and found a few methods, but I am unsure of which is correct because I can not find anything specific for this netbook:

- Remove CMOS battery for a few minutes
- Short pins on the CMOS or EEPROM
- Use an EEPROM reader to get the password

Does this netbook store the password in the EEPROM? If so, how do I reset it? Or can it be reset just simply by taking out the CMOS battery?

EDIT: I just found [this](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-Z-and-P-series/Bios-Recovery-For-ideapad-laptops/td-p/884237). Would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, there are two methods of doing this:

1. Clear the CMOS by removing the battery and shorting the reset pins (requires moving a jumper *usually not available on netbooks*, refer to motherboard manual for that). Doesn't always work.
2. Reflash the BIOS. You'll get rid of the password for sure, but it it fails you'll get rid of the motherboard too. The link you found requires BIOS flashing which makes me think this is the only way of removing the password. This is not a risk-free procedure. Be sure to follow [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-common-mistakes-you-should-avoid-when-flashing-your-bios/).